# My TableViewer is not sorting properly after I added a DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a JFace TableViewer with a ViewerComparator. The direction and column of the sort is set on the selection listener of the table. This works just fine.

However, I recently changed my LabelProvider from a `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` to a `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider`. After I made that change, the table seems to be sorting - the column gets highlighted and the directional arrow is added to the column header. The first column gets sorted the way I was expecting based on the values of the sorting column, but the rest of the rows aren't moving with it.

This is how the table looks before I try to sort. Notice the value of the first column in relation to the other values.

[image: Before sorting]

And after I sort. See how the 2nd column's values are in the same order they were before even though the first column is alphabetical?

[image: after sorting]

My code for adding the `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider` is as follows:

```html
        column.setLabelProvider( 
                new DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider(
                        new MyStyledCellLabelProvider(),
                        MyPlugin.getDefault().getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager(),
                        null ) );
```

Edited to add the compare code

```html
    @Override
public int compare( final Viewer viewer, final Object e1, final Object e2 ) {
    if( !( e1 instanceof TreeElement<?>  &&  e2 instanceof TreeElement<?> ) ) {
        return super.compare(viewer, e1, e2);
    }

    if(this.sortDirection == SortDirection.NONE) {
        return ((TreeElement<?>) e1).getSortIndex() - ((TreeElement<?>) e2).getSortIndex();
    }

    final IBaseLabelProvider labelProvider = ((ColumnViewer) viewer).getLabelProvider(this.columnNumber);
    if( !(labelProvider instanceof DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider) ) {
        return super.compare(viewer, e1, e2);
    }
    final IStyledLabelProvider columnLabelProvider = ((DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider) labelProvider).getStyledStringProvider();

    final TreeElement<?> treeElement1 = (TreeElement<?>) e1;
    final String text1 = columnLabelProvider.getStyledText(treeElement1).getString();

    final TreeElement<?> treeElement2 = (TreeElement<?>) e2;
    final String text2 = columnLabelProvider.getStyledText(treeElement2).getString();

    // either one could be null
    int result;
    if(text1 == null) {
        result = text2 == null ? 
                    0 : // both null, so they're the same 
                    1;  // only text1 is null, so text2 is greater
    } else {
        result = text2 == null ? 
                    -1 : // only text2 is null, so text1 is greater
                    text1.compareToIgnoreCase(text2); // both not null - do a real text compare 
    }

    // If descending order, flip the direction
    return this.sortDirection == SortDirection.DESCENDING ? -result : result;
}
```

EDIT 2: Adding label provider code.
My label provider extends `ColumnLabelProvider` and implements `IStyledLabelProvider`

```html
    @Override
public StyledString getStyledText(final Object element) {
    if( !(element instanceof TreeElement<?>) ) {
        return null;
    }

    final String elemText = getText(element);
    final StyledString styledString = new StyledString(elemText == null ? "" : elemText);

    if( !(element instanceof MyElement<?,?>) ) {
        return styledString;
    }
    // apply styles as needed
    return styledString;
}
```

EDIT 3: Resolution

I wasn't able to fix the issue. However, it became moot as I was able to work out a change in the design so I didn't need the DecoratingStyledCellLableProvider anyway. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You will have to show us your code that does the sorting

Comment: The sort looks like it is probably OK. What about the label provider for the second column?

Comment: My label provider is the same for all the columns. In actuality, I pass the column index to the constructor and then get the text based on the columnIndex. The logic is kind of complex, and I'm not sure if I can simplify it enough to be able to post here. Is there something specific that I can look for?

Comment: I figured out a way to simplify. Posting the getStyledText() part of the label provider.

Comment: Are you calling `refresh()` on the viewer when the sort direction changes - I think this is necessary.

Comment: Yes I am.   `tree.setSortDirection(dir);
    tree.setSortColumn(column);
    MyPage.this.viewer.refresh();`

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your label provider when gathering the data for the second column. The sort is performed only once to reorganize the elements between them, then each columnLabelProvider is called to render each element.

Comment: Until I changed to a DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider, I wasn't having any issues with sorting. My getStyledText() uses the same method for getting the text that my original method did.